# Issue in establishing connection with Rabbit MQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq

code

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;


public class Send {
private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "test";

public static void main(String[] argv) throws java.io.IOException {
    try {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");

        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        System.out.println(connection.getPort());
        System.out.println(connection.getAddress());

        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
        System.out.println("opening channel");
        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        String message = "Hello World!";
        channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
        channel.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();

    }

}
}
```

I am getting the below exception:-

```
1. java.io.IOException  at
    com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)   at
    com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)   at
    com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124)
        at
    com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:844)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:61)
        at com.in.test.Send.main(Send.java:24) Caused by:
    com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol
    method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406,
    reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'durable' for
    queue 'test' in vhost '/': received 'false' but current is 'true',
    class-id=50, method-id=10)  at
    com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
        at
    com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
        at
    com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:361)
        at
    com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:226)
        at
    com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)
        ... 3 more Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException:
    channel error; protocol method:
    #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'durable' for
    queue 'test' in vhost '/': received 'false' but current is 'true',
    class-id=50, method-id=10)  at
    com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:484)
        at
    com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:321)
        at
    com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
        at
    com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
        at
    com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:554)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 17):

This is happening since your pre-existing channel on your RabbitMQ server, named `test`, was created with durable set `true`:

```
channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
                                 ----
```

You've since changed your code like so:

```
channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
                                 -----
```

You need to remove the channel from your server ([rabbitmqctl](https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html)), or create a new channel (unique name).

I'd say your answer solved your problem since you renamed your queue, but you didn't reflect this in your answer.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but here it is opposite. Existing queue was set durable = true. But later user tried to create it as durable=false.

Answer (score 7):

Just change the line `channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);`
to `channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);`

This worked for me.

Comment: Yes, queue declare parameters can't be changed between invocations.

Comment: The error message here explains the issue: protocol
    method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406,
    reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'durable' for
    queue 'test' in vhost '/': received 'false' but current is 'true'

Answer (score 1):

do that once:
1.run you app with consumer durable=true in channel.queueDeclare
let it connect the queue
2.close it.
3.start the producer

now you wont get this exception